# Parse empty field to XML

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

i am parsing class with empty string in some element in XML file like below.

```
objectCxml.Request.InvoiceDetailRequest.InvoiceDetailRequestHeader.InvoiceDetailHeaderIndicator = "";
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(cXML));
XmlTextWriter tw = new XmlTextWriter(path, Encoding.UTF8);
s.Serialize(tw, objectCxml);
```

It generate xml like below

```
<InvoiceDetailHeaderIndicator xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
```

But i want it as below

```
<InvoiceDetailHeaderIndicator/>
```

Any Suggestion?

Comment: welll, what is `InvoiceDetailRequestHeader`? can we see the class and `InvoiceDetailHeaderIndicator` property here? is it perhaps `object`?

Comment: InvoiceDetailHeaderIndicator property is object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> InvoiceDetailHeaderIndicator property is `object`

So... don't do that? Make it `string` and you should be set.

Ultimately, the point here is that `XmlSerializer` wants to be able to round-trip data reliably; that is its job. There are two ways of doing that:

1. know the type statically (i.e. `string` instead of `object` in the type model)
2. embed additional metadata in the payload (`xsi:type="xsd:string"`)

If you don't want 2, you'll need 1, otherwise *it can't work*. Frankly 1 is a much better idea *anyway*.

I tested with a local minimal setup, and this worked fine:

```cs
public class InvoiceHeaderThing
{
    public string InvoiceDetailHeaderIndicator { get; set; }
}
```

Full code below:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        const string path = "my.xml";

        var objectCxml = new cXML();
        objectCxml.Request.InvoiceDetailRequest.InvoiceDetailRequestHeader.InvoiceDetailHeaderIndicator = "";
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(cXML));
        using (XmlTextWriter tw = new XmlTextWriter(path, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            s.Serialize(tw, objectCxml);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(File.ReadAllText(path));
    }
}

public class cXML
{
    public RequestThing Request { get; set; } = new RequestThing();
}
public class RequestThing
{
    public InvoiceDetailThing InvoiceDetailRequest { get; set; } = new InvoiceDetailThing();
}
public class InvoiceDetailThing
{
    public InvoiceHeaderThing InvoiceDetailRequestHeader { get; set; } = new InvoiceHeaderThing();
}
public class InvoiceHeaderThing
{
    public string InvoiceDetailHeaderIndicator { get; set; }
}
```